# Can I Format A String Like A Number in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

If I had a phone number like this

```
string phone = "6365555796";
```

Which I store with only numeric characters in my database **(as a string)**, is it possible to output the number like this:

```
"636-555-5796"
```

Similar to how I could if I were using a number:

```
long phone = 6365555796;
string output = phone.ToString("000-000-0000");
```

I've tried searching and all I could find online were numeric formatting documents.

The reason I ask is because I think it would be an interesting idea to be able to store only the numeric values in the DB and allow for different formatting using a Constant string value to dictate how my phone numbers are formatted. Or am I better off using a number for this?

EDIT: The question is to format a string that contains numbers, not a number itself.

Comment: I deleted my original answer, and edited the question to clarify why I got it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best I can think of without having to convert to a long/number and so it fits one line is:

```
string number = "1234567890";
string formattedNumber = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", number.Substring(0,3), number.Substring(3,3), number.Substring(6));
```

Answer (score 6):

Be aware that not everyone uses the North American 3-3-4 format for phone numbers. European phone numbers can be up to 15 digits long, with significant punctuation, e.g. +44-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX is different from 44+XXXX-XXXX-XXXX. You are also not considering PBXs and extensions, which can require over 30 digits.

Military and radio phones can have alphabetic characters, no this is not the "2" = "ABC" you see on touch-tone phones.

Comment: My app. is only storing US numbers in the 10 digit format. If extensions are needed they will be stored in a separate field. We're storing numbers for comparison since phone numbers entered will need to be compared and stripping out all non-numerics guarantees user formatting won't break that.

Answer (score 6):

The simple version:

```
string phone = "6365555796";
Convert.ToInt64(phone).ToString("000-000-0000");
```

To wrap some validation around that and put it in a nice method:

```
string FormatPhone(string phone)
{
   /*assume the phone string came from the database, so we already know it's
     only digits.  If this changes in the future a simple RegEx can validate 
     (or correct) the digits requirement. */

   // still want to check the length:
   if (phone.Length != 10) throw new InvalidArgumentException();

  return Convert.ToInt64(phone).ToString("000-000-0000");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this works

```
string s = string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", ulong.Parse(phone));
```

In addtion, this http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/ is a nice post on formatting strings in .NET.

Thanks to @swilliams for clarifications.

Comment: Heh, I had copied the URL to paste it onto my post, but forgot to for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do something like this?

```
string phoneText = "6365555796";
long phoneNum = long.Parse(phoneText);
string output = phoneNum.ToString("000-000-0000");
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but if I want to include the numbers in an ASP.NET Gridview or a Repeater it would require extra code to output the numbers correctly. I was wondering if there was a one-line .NET function I was somehow overlooking...

Comment: You already have the answer by swilliams. But you can employ this functionality as well in "one line" if you use anonymous delegate.

Comment: If the number has leading 0, then you might get erroneous output

Answer (score 1):

I loves me some extension method action:

```
   /// <summary>
   ///   Formats a string of nine digits into a U.S. phone number.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="value">
   ///   The string to format as a phone number.
   /// </param>
   /// <returns>
   ///   The numeric string as a U.S. phone number.
   /// </returns>
   public static string
   ToUSPhone (this string value)
   {
      if (value == null)
      {
         return null;
      }

      long  dummy;

      if ((value.Length != 10) ||
         !long.TryParse (
            value,
            NumberStyles.None,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            out dummy))
      {
         return value;
      }

      return string.Format (
         CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
         "{0}-{1}-{2}",
         value.Substring (0, 3),
         value.Substring (3, 3),
         value.Substring (6));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do a string insert at a given character point. Kinda like: 
phone = phone.Insert(3, "-");
phone = phone.Insert(7, "-");

Comment: This is "slow", as it will lead to a lot of string creations.

Comment: It should be faster then parsing a long, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
Regex.Replace(phone, @"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$", @"$1-$2-$3")
```

Of course, [now you have 2 problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html).

Answer (score -1):

To control string format of a number for display in an ASP.NET Gridview or another control, you can wrap your item in a helper class for display purposes:

```
public class PhoneDisplay
{
    long phoneNum;
    public PhoneDisplay(long number)
    {
        phoneNum = number;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:###-###-####}", phoneNum);
    }

}
```

Then, define data or display fields as (e.g.):

```
PhoneDisplay MyPhone = new PhoneDisplay(6365555796);
```